# How to create a page in Gatsby from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-context

I am trying to create a page dynamically in Gatsby using JSON file. In that file, I am defining the components that should be rendered in the page.

I followed the documentation of Gatsby, however, it doesn't have what I want. So I tried to create the pages by reading the JSON file and traversing through the components in it and creating them using React.createElement(). At the end I got an array of react components which I passed to a children prop in the context object of the createPage method to the template page component.

Is it the right way to tackle this idea? And is it doable in Gatsby or not?

I think it is useful to say that I tried dynamic import and it worked fine, but I'm trying to find a way where I don't have to dump all my components in one folder.

I have a Github repo for this project.
https://github.com/ahmedalbeiruti/Gatsby-dynamic-pages

And here is the main parts of the code:

gatsby-node.js

```
exports.createPages = ({actions})=>{
    const {createPage} = actions
    const resutl = componentsRenderer(data.page.layout.columns)
    createPage({
        path: data.page.name,
        component: path.resolve('./src/template/page.js'),
        context:{
            children: resutl
        }
    })
}

const componentsRenderer = components => {

    return components.map(component => {
        let children = []
        if (component.children){
            children = componentsRenderer(component.children)
        }
        const element = require(`${__dirname}/${component.path}`)

        return React.createElement(element, Object.assign({},{key: component.key},{...component.props}),children)
    });
}
```

data/sample-page-no-props.json

```
{
        "page":{
            "name": "about",
            "layout":{
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "key":"column_1",
                        "name": "Column",
                        "path": "/src/components/layouts/column.jsx",
                        "children":[
                            {
                                "name": "FirstComponent",
                                "path": "/src/components/custom/first-component.jsx",
                                "key": "first_component_1"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "column_2",
                        "name": "Column",
                        "path": "/src/components/layouts/column.jsx",
                        "children":[
                            {
                                "key": "second_component_1",
                                "name": "SecondComponent",
                                "path": "/src/components/custom/second-component.jsx",
                                "children":[
                                    {
                                        "key": "leaf_component_1",
                                        "name": "LeafComponent",
                                        "path":"/src/components/custom/leaf-component.jsx"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "third_component_1",
                                "name": "ThirdComponent",
                                "path": "/src/components/custom/third-component.jsx",
                                "children":[
                                    {
                                        "key": "leaf_component_1",
                                        "name": "LeafComponent",
                                        "path":"/src/components/custom/leaf-component.jsx"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
}
```

data/sample-page-with-style-prop.json (FirstComponent has props object)

```
{
        "page":{
            "name": "about",
            "layout":{
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "key":"column_1",
                        "name": "Column",
                        "path": "/src/components/layouts/column.jsx",
                        "children":[
                            {
                                "name": "FirstComponent",
                                "path": "/src/components/custom/first-component.jsx",
                                "key": "first_component_1",
                                "props":{
                                    "style":{
                                        "color":"red"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "column_2",
                        "name": "Column",
                        "path": "/src/components/layouts/column.jsx",
                        "children":[
                            {
                                "key": "second_component_1",
                                "name": "SecondComponent",
                                "path": "/src/components/custom/second-component.jsx",
                                "children":[
                                    {
                                        "key": "leaf_component_1",
                                        "name": "LeafComponent",
                                        "path":"/src/components/custom/leaf-component.jsx"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "third_component_1",
                                "name": "ThirdComponent",
                                "path": "/src/components/custom/third-component.jsx",
                                "children":[
                                    {
                                        "key": "leaf_component_1",
                                        "name": "LeafComponent",
                                        "path":"/src/components/custom/leaf-component.jsx"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
}
```

template/page.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layouts/Layout'

const Page = (props)=>{
    console.log(`page_context: ${props.pageContext.children}`)
    return (
        <>
        <h1>this is the about page</h1>
        <Layout>
            {props.pageContext.children}
        </Layout>
        </>
    )
}

export default Page
```

components/custom/first-component.jsx

```
// import React from "react";

const React = require("react");

module.exports = (props)=>{
    return(
        <h3 style={props.style}>
            Hi this is the first component
        </h3>
    )
}

// export default FirstComponent
```

The error that I'm getting when using the sample-page-with-style-prop.json file is the following:

```
UNHANDLED REJECTION Cannot assign to read only property 'style' of object '#<Object>'

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'style' of object '#<Object>'
```

And if I change to sample-page-no-props.json file I get the following error:

```
UNHANDLED REJECTION Cannot assign to read only property 'children' of object '#<Object>'

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'children' of object '#<Object>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the components as context to the page template. The right way would be pass on the data and render the component within Page

**gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.createPages = ({actions})=>{
    const {createPage} = actions
    const resutl = componentsRenderer(data.page.layout.columns)
    createPage({
        path: data.page.name,
        component: path.resolve('./src/template/page.js'),
        context:{
            children: resutl
        }
    })
}
```

**template/page.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layouts/Layout'

const componentsRenderer = components => {

    return components.map(component => {
        let children = []
        if (component.children){
            children = componentsRenderer(component.children)
        }
        const element = require(`${HOME_DIR}/${component.path}`)

        return React.createElement(element, Object.assign({},{key: component.key},{...component.props}),children)
    });
}
const Page = (props)=>{
    const data = props.pageContext.children
    return (
        <>
        <h1>this is the about page</h1>
        <Layout>
            {componentsRenderer(data)}
        </Layout>
        </>
    )
}

export default Page
```

PS: Make sure the `HOME_DIR` path is correct in the page component.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I was trying your suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work. I got the error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. It is probably because I didn't change the require to es6 import (actually using loadable-components) but this will make it a dynamic import which I already done and it worked fine. I am looking for alternatives as my team opted for not doing dynamic import.

Comment: Seems like you should export the components as default and import as default like `const element = require(\`${HOME_DIR}/${component.path}\`).default`